# Error when upgrading umbraco 4 blog package

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog

I'm getting the error as outlined here http://blog4umbraco.codeplex.com/workitem/5399. The page says the issue has been resolved and one of the comments provides sql statements to modify the dataTypes. However, the sql statements don't work. The error I get, as in the post, is 'Could not find datatype with id 71b8ad1a-8dc2-425c-b6b8-faa158075e63' so searching for this id in the cmsDataType table is returning nothing and leaving me with nothing to modify.

I've been upgrading from umbraco 3.0, managed to get to v4 but whilst I could see the blog on the front end no problem trying to edit a post in the back end was showing an error when clicking on the blog post (error page was appearing on the right where the content edit pane would normally appear). Since my next step was to upgrade to v4.5.2 (on the path to getting to 4.7) I wondered if it might fix up, but it hasn't. My logical choice was to upgrade the blog (as the original blog was the old blog package from 2006). So it's now screwed up. :(

Can anyone throw some light on the issue or tell me how I can get the blog package upgraded?

Comment: I would try searching using a like statement and just passing the first few characters of the guid.  i.e. select * from cmsdatatype where controlid like '71b8ad%'.  Does that return anything?  I've had issues sometimes trying to locate a guid by passing a string...

Comment: what blog package are you using? Have you tried removing the package and reinstalling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what blog package are you using? Have you tried removing the package and reinstalling it?

By the sounds of it the database is corrupt. Before i continue i would say to back it all up so you have a starting point to try and fix it...

You can then make a package back up of your data nodes this is done under developer packages. If all goes well you will be able to add this package and it will figure out what datatype it is by alias.. It is not sure fire and that is why i say back up.

I would then recommend removing the packages(blog) that have added the datatypes. You could also do this manually under settings.

You can do this in developer -> Packages also by picking what content nodes to back up. Remove and then re-add you blog package then try to push the data back over the top.

- **Alternative** is to do a clean install of 4.7. Install the blog package then make a package with just your data in it. I would prefer to do it like this if possible as many many small things change from version to version. I did what you are doing now and i have lost packages(as they are used in a diffent way.. no longer stored in ~/umbraco but now ~/App_Data/Packages/) these changes make a big difference when you upgrade from old versions tho.